# Автоматическая печать данных

Tags: php, печать, javascript

Есть код, который заполняет БД.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['message_wall']) )
{
    include('config.php');

    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message_wall']); 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `wall` (`message`) VALUES( '".$message."')";
    mysql_query($sql);

    echo $message;
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Мне нужно, чтоб одновременно с ним отправлялась печать на принтер. С яво скриптом так у меня не получилось, только нужно делать кнопку отправить.

```
<script language="javascript">
function CallPrint(strid)
{
 var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
 var prtCSS = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/css/template.css" type="text/css" />';
 var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=50,top=50,width=800,height=640,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
 WinPrint.document.write('<div id="print" class="contentpane">');
 WinPrint.document.write(prtCSS);
 WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
 WinPrint.document.write('</div>');
 WinPrint.document.close();
 WinPrint.focus();
 WinPrint.print();
 WinPrint.close();
 prtContent.innerHTML=strOldOne;
}
</script>

<a onClick="javascript:CallPrint('print-content');" title="Распечатать проект">Распечатать</a>
```

Еще раз, методом пост отправляются данные, где этот пхп код их записывает в бд. Мне нужно чтоб вместе с этим отправлялась печать на притер. Наверное еще нужно будет как-то отформатировать для печати.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, взял вот такую, урезанную версию

```
<script language="javascript">
function CallPrint(strid)
{
 var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=50,top=50,width=800,height=640,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
 WinPrint.document.write('Test');
 WinPrint.document.close();
 WinPrint.focus();
 WinPrint.print();
 WinPrint.close();
 prtContent.innerHTML=strOldOne;
}
</script>

<a onClick="javascript:CallPrint('print-content');">Print</a>
```

и все работает.
JS не отлаживали? Может где ошибки лезут. JS ведь не многословен в таких случаях.

Comment: ну мне не нужна кнопка, мне нужно чтоб автоматически отправлялась печать в месте с базой

Comment: "автоматически" на печать ничего не отправится, максимум выскочит окно выбора устройства печати, аналогичное нажатию Ctrl+P в браузере

Comment: на счет окна я уже позаботился ничего не вылазит!!!
когда нажимаешь отправить , сразу печатает принтер без всяких окошек...только мне нужно что б срабатывало без нажатия на кнопку....а при обновлении страници например

Comment: Можно вызвать функцию при загрузке страницы, напр.:
$(document).ready(function(){
CallPrint('print-content');
});